# как преобразовать типа %5B3%5D на salon[4] через jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Как преобразовать типа %5B3%5D на salon[4] через jQuery ?

```
var url = '/account?act=articles&get=add&'+$('#add > input').serialize()+'&'+$('#add #fileds').find('select, textarea, input').serialize();
console.log( url );
```

> /account?a%5B3%5D=%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE&b%5B4%5D=%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0

типа на

> /account?a[17]=ascdcsdcsdc&b[20]=dfhdfhfhfd

Comment: Вот `decodeURI()`

Comment: @br3t спасибо вот что надо!